# tabStripEnabled for TabWidget in Older API's

Tags: android

Android 2.2 i.e API Level 8 has tabStripEnabled="true" for TabWidget
how to achieve the same in Older versions of Android?

Comment: I had the Tabs at the bottom of the screen,
So I did it as below...

<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="55dip"
   android:layout_marginBottom="-10dip" android:layout_weight="0"
   android:background="#000000" />

I put android:layout_marginBottom="-10dip" moving the bottomStrip off the screen

but want to know the exact way to do it...
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private void SetupTabs(TabHost tabHost) {

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tabHost.getChildAt(0);
    TabWidget tw = (TabWidget) ll.getChildAt(0);

    Field mBottomLeftStrip;
    Field mBottomRightStrip;

    try {
        mBottomLeftStrip = tw.getClass().getDeclaredField("mBottomLeftStrip");
        mBottomRightStrip = tw.getClass().getDeclaredField("mBottomRightStrip");

        if (!mBottomLeftStrip.isAccessible()) {
            mBottomLeftStrip.setAccessible(true);
        }

        if (!mBottomRightStrip.isAccessible()) {
            mBottomRightStrip.setAccessible(true);
        }

        mBottomLeftStrip.set(tw, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blank));
        mBottomRightStrip.set(tw, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blank));// blank is the name of the image in drawable folder

    } 
    catch (java.lang.NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // possibly 2.2
        try {
            Method stripEnabled = tw.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setStripEnabled", boolean.class);
            stripEnabled.invoke(tw, false);

        } 
        catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I tried it both on a 2.1 and 2.2 emulator. Is there anything else that I should consider when using this hack?

It correctly executed code based on the current SDK but the bottom border for the TabWidget remained.

Comment: This worked perfect, some things to note, create a transparent image and name it blank.  I made a slight change by commenting out:
    
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tabHost.getChildAt(0);
    TabWidget tw = (TabWidget) ll.getChildAt(0);
    
and replacing with
    
    TabWidget tw = tabHost.getTabWidget();

Answer (score 0):

I made it so:

```
try {
        Method setStripEnabled = tabWidget.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                "setStripEnabled", boolean.class);
        setStripEnabled.invoke(tabWidget, true);

        Method setLeftStripDrawable = tabWidget.getClass()
                .getDeclaredMethod("setLeftStripDrawable", int.class);
        setLeftStripDrawable.invoke(tabWidget, R.drawable.tab_line);

        Method setRightStripDrawable = tabWidget.getClass()
                .getDeclaredMethod("setRightStripDrawable", int.class);
        setRightStripDrawable.invoke(tabWidget, R.drawable.tab_line);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```