# Android TabHost Border Line

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tabStripEnabled for TabWidget in Older API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164325/tabstripenabled-for-tabwidget-in-older-apis)

The TabHost BorderLine are present in my app but I don't want this.

I have the solution are in Android 2.2 using "android:tabStripEnabled==False".

But I want Solution in version Android 1.6 and above.

Thankx